# É possível customizar o diálogo nativo de permissões do navegador?

Tags: segurança, navegador-de-internet, ux, permissões

Alguém sabe me dizer como posso, e se é que é possível, manipular via JavaScript a notificação de autorização para ativar o microfone do browser cliente?

Meu objetivo não é acessar sem a permissão do usuário, isso certamente não deve ser possível, mas melhorar a caixa que exibe a mensagem.

Gostaria de aumentar e deixar claro pois estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que o microfone terá que ser usado e nos primeiros testes que fiz, notei que o usuário muitas vezes não percebe essa notificação e "pula" a etapa de autorizar a abertura do microfone.

[image]

Comment: Por ser um recurso nativo dos browsers, acredito que não será possível alterar sua aparência. Mas seria um recurso bem interessante.

Answer (score 3):

Não existe como fazer isso. Essa decisão é intencional e extremamente importante para a segurança dos usuários.

Navegadores são programas que executam código arbitrário no computador do usuário. E, a depender das funcionalidades que o código executado precisa executar, é necessário pedir a permissão explícita do usuário.

Essa permissão é concedida pelo usuário por uma interface totalmente padronizada que faz parte da interface do próprio navegador. Todos os sites que você visita têm a mesma aparência para manter a experiência consistente.

Essa impossibilidade de customização também é importante para prevenir interfaces que induzam a aceitação do usuário através da omissão de informações sobre o que realmente está sendo pedido. Como o navegador validaria que, de fato, o *dialog* de permissão customizado dá todas as informações para que o usuário tome uma decisão consciente? A verdade é que não é possível fazer esse tipo de determinação, ao menos não de modo eficiente com as tecnologias atuais.

O que você pode fazer é, antes de solicitar a autorização do usuário pela interface do navegador, abrir um *popup* próprio (e customizado) ou mostrar uma seta como indicativo, como “por favor, a seguir você será solicitado para aceitar as permissões para que essa interface funcione”.

Sites como o Facebook fazem isso e dá um pouco mais de ”fluidez”, mas a interface nativa ainda continua ali.

[image: Demonstração do popover do Facebook]

Nesse caso, uma vez que eu clico em "Ativar" (está pouco visível na imagem), o código JavaScript do Facebook chama a API que exibe o diálogo nativo de permissão.